# Getting Google Analytics data without needing to login

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I've played around the the Analytics API and used oauth and managed to pull data from my Analytics account, this wasn't too much of a bother and worked really well.

The problem is I'm building a small "data graphing" service for me clients, this will basically feed data from Google Analytics, Telephone tracking and a few other services into a central area that'll display how many people are contacting them from their website.

The problem is that to use the Google Analytic API you need to be authenticated by oauth, this prompts the user to log into a Google account.

Is there a way in which I can get my GA data without the need to manually authenticate with oauth?

Comment: Take a good look at the [Authorization methods](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization#common_oauth) available. There are 2 that should work for you. **Web Server** and **Service Accounts**. With the [Web Server](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) method you still have to go through oAuth, but you have to do it only once. And then after that you get a refresh token that you can use to generate more access tokens when needed without going through oAuth flow again. The [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accou

Answer (score 1):

You could try **GAPI - Google Analytics API PHP Interface**

Here's the Google Code page of this project:
http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

**Features** (as mentioned on the GAPI project page):

- Supports CURL and fopen HTTP access methods, with autodetection
- PHP arrays for Google Analytics metrics and dimensions
- Account data object mapping - get methods for parameters
- Report data object mapping - get methods for metrics and parameters
- Easy filtering, use a GAPI query language for Google Analytics filters
- Full PHP5 Object Oriented code, ready for use in your PHP application